# custom view draws a rectangle

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've got a custom view with the following drawRect method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    float w = rect.size.width;

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextAddArc(ctx, w / 2, w / 2, w / 2 - 10,  0, 2 * M_PI, 0); 
    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFill);

}
```

I'm expecting to see a black circle, however, for some reason it draws a black rectangle instead. I guess the whole view is just getting filled with black. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your view's `backgroundColor` is also black (which is the default for opaque views)?

Also, you shouldn't assume that the `rect` parameter covers the whole view, it could be only a part of the view that has been marked as needing to be redrawn. You should base your geometry calculations on the view's `bounds` instead.

Comment: Thanks, adding `self.opaque = NO` appears to have sorted it out

Answer (score 2):

You need to add....

```
[super drawRect:rect];
```

as the first line, this will then render the background as per the views background property, OR if you prefer you can fill the context with the background colour yourself, I prefer the former.

Comment: Thanks! It turned out that I actually want my view's background to be transparent, as per omz's answer

Comment: You should still either call the super method or handle the drawing based on the set colour, if you change the colour later (from transparent) it won't work as you are not following the rules for overriding drawRect properly. Just wearing my 'proper' code hat ;)

Comment: Calling `super` has no effect for `drawRect:` because the default implementation [does nothing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect:).

Comment: Unless there is an intermediary class....in which case you are potentially bypassing required code. Good development dictates that when overriding any method you should ALWAYS call the super implementation at some point unless you wish to completely bypass any previous behaviour. In this case it may do nothing but it's not good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you clip it that it will be shaped into the right size?

```
 CGContextClip(context);
```

(Why aren't you using `CGMutablePathRef` btw?)

Comment: He's missing a super call OR manually filling the context with the views background colour, nothing to do with clipping.

Comment: I have zero experience with "CGMutablePathRef", could you elaborate what is it good for?

Comment: It is easily googled. But with it you can draw and store and recreate shapes very easily. You can also easily assign linethickness, linecolor, filling and much much more.